# qf in solr search query not working as expected

Tags: search, solr, lucene

In my schema.xml, entry for all fields is as follows:

```
   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
   <field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="manu" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true"/>
   <field name="producturl" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" required="true"/>
   <field name="imageurl" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" />
   <field name="category" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true"/>
   <field name="categorypath" type="lowercase" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="weight" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="price"  type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="popularity" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="inStock" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="last_modified" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="store" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true"/>
```

and I'm trying the search in which search string if exist in category must come above the resule where search string exist in name. I tried the following query but I'm always getting the result where query sting is present in name.

http:///solr//select?debugQuery=on&indent=on&q=*query*:"{!edismax mm='100%25' qf='manu^10.0' v=$q1}" OR *query*:"{!edismax mm='100%25' qf='name^0.2' v=$q1}" OR *query*:"{!edismax mm='100%25' qf='category^10.0' v=$q1}" OR *query*:"{!edismax mm='100%25' qf='categorypath^5.0' v=$q1}"&q1=mobile&wt=csv

Result snippet for above query is as follows:

```
mrp_d,manu,description,discount_i,store,_version_,price,categorypath,imageurl,name,id,category,producturl,last_modified
60.68,Not Specified,,50,Lazada,1549123070131699713,30.34,Women|Wallets & Accessories,http://srv-live.lazada.com.my/p/image-78714241-16244bcc8b6488fa7c5dc3479b6b6f69-product.jpg,Fashion Women Lady Cute Cat Clutch Long Purse Wallet Card Holder Mobile Bag Green,LZDNO037FAAA8H917ANMY-18042381,Wallets & Accessories,http://ho.lazada.com.my/SHHSoo?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lazada.com.my%2Ffashion-women-lady-cute-cat-clutch-long-purse-wallet-card-holder-mobile-bag-green-14241787.html%3Foffer_id%3D%7Boffer_id%7D%26affiliate_id%3D%7Baffiliate_id%7D%26offer_name%3D%7Boffer_name%7D_%7Boffer_file_id%7D%26affiliate_name%3D%7Baffiliate_name%7D%26transaction_id%3D%7Btransaction_id%7D&aff_sub=&aff_sub2=&aff_sub3=&aff_sub4=&aff_sub5=,2016-10-25T01:27:53Z
60.3,Not Specified,,50,Lazada,1549123070201954306,30.15,Women|Wallets & Accessories,http://srv-live.lazada.com.my/p/image-53144241-27196219e745476ccd5b10cb0febf37b-product.jpg,Fashion Women Flower Long Zip Wallet Card Holder Mobile Bag Clutch Purse Pockets Navy Blue,LZDNO037FAAA8HAUFANMY-18045720,Wallets & Accessories,http://ho.lazada.com.my/SHHSoo?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lazada.com.my%2Ffashion-women-flower-long-zip-wallet-card-holder-mobile-bag-clutch-purse-pockets-navy-blue-14244135.html%3Foffer_id%3D%7Boffer_id%7D%26affiliate_id%3D%7Baffiliate_id%7D%26offer_name%3D%7Boffer_name%7D_%7Boffer_file_id%7D%26affiliate_name%3D%7Baffiliate_name%7D%26transaction_id%3D%7Btransaction_id%7D&aff_sub=&aff_sub2=&aff_sub3=&aff_sub4=&aff_sub5=,2016-10-25T01:27:53Z
84.66,Not Specified,,66,Lazada,1549123070268014594,28.22,Women|Bags & Clutches|Handbags,http://srv-live.lazada.com.my/p/image-63215241-13718b9bf73f9ba09610037ef9ac8dad-product.jpg,ERA New Women Vintage Leather Coin Cell Phone Mobile Mini Cross-body Shoulder Bag,LZDNO037FAAA8HGBOANMY-18055171,Handbags,http://ho.lazada.com.my/SHHSoo?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lazada.com.my%2Fera-new-women-vintage-leather-coin-cell-phone-mobile-mini-cross-body-shoulder-bag-14251236.html%3Foffer_id%3D%7Boffer_id%7D%26affiliate_id%3D%7Baffiliate_id%7D%26offer_name%3D%7Boffer_name%7D_%7Boffer_file_id%7D%26affiliate_name%3D%7Baffiliate_name%7D%26transaction_id%3D%7Btransaction_id%7D&aff_sub=&aff_sub2=&aff_sub3=&aff_sub4=&aff_sub5=,2016-10-25T01:27:53Z
84.66,Not Specified,,66,Lazada,1549123070268014595,28.22,Women|Bags & Clutches|Handbags,http://srv-live.lazada.com.my/p/image-93215241-08f2151a427d52295328a5d7e5addce1-product.jpg,ERA New Women Vintage Leather Coin Cell Phone Mobile Mini Cross-body Shoulder Bag,LZDNO037FAAA8HGBRANMY-18055174,Handbags,http://ho.lazada.com.my/SHHSoo?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lazada.com.my%2Fera-new-women-vintage-leather-coin-cell-phone-mobile-mini-cross-body-shoulder-bag-14251239.html%3Foffer_id%3D%7Boffer_id%7D%26affiliate_id%3D%7Baffiliate_id%7D%26offer_name%3D%7Boffer_name%7D_%7Boffer_file_id%7D%26affiliate_name%3D%7Baffiliate_name%7D%26transaction_id%3D%7Btransaction_id%7D&aff_sub=&aff_sub2=&aff_sub3=&aff_sub4=&aff_sub5=,2016-10-25T01:27:53Z
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I fine tune the results?

Thanks in advance for help.

Edit (xml results with debug results):

Query:
http:///solr//select?debugQuery=on&defType=edismax&indent=on&mm=3&ps=10&q=mobile&qf=category^10.0%20manu^10.0%20categorypath^5.0%20name^0.2&wt=xml

Complete response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">26</int>
  <lst name="params">
    <str name="mm">3</str>
    <str name="q">mobile</str>
    <str name="defType">edismax</str>
    <str name="ps">10</str>
    <str name="indent">on</str>
    <str name="qf">category^10.0 manu^10.0 categorypath^5.0 name^0.2</str>
    <str name="wt">xml</str>
    <str name="debugQuery">on</str>
    <str name="_">1477372296342</str>
  </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="12450223" start="0">
  <doc>
    <str name="description">This vertical case is made from PU leather material, and specially designed for your smartphone. The case features card slot and earphone hole for convenient use. It can be used as a shoulder bag or holster case. ? Made from PU material ? Come with two card slot ? Used as a shoulder bag and holster case ? Provides all-around protection</str>
    <int name="discount_i">40</int>
    <double name="mrp_d">990.0</double>
    <str name="store">Flipkart</str>
    <float name="price">490.0</float>
    <str name="categorypath">Mobiles &amp; Tablets|Mobile Accessories|Cases &amp; Covers</str>
    <str name="imageurl">http://img5a.flixcart.com/image/cases-covers/holster/h/c/x/jojo-jojo288086-400x400-imae822ffdyrhgmg.jpeg</str>
    <str name="name">Jojo Holster for Fly Mobile MV 247</str>
    <str name="id">ACCE9GQ3BMCHZXYY</str>
    <str name="category">Cases &amp; Covers</str>
    <str name="manu">Jojo</str>
    <str name="producturl">http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/jojo-holster-fly-mobile-mv-247/p/itme9gq44hz9dtjh?pid=ACCE9GQ3BMCHZXYY</str>
    <date name="last_modified">2016-10-21T07:40:13Z</date>
    <long name="_version_">1548784125563895810</long></doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="description">Mobile Cover Shop having numerous designs of exclusive range for mobile covers, back cover and protective cover and cases. Each cover is made from a special strong and durable plastic material, which provides your gadget with long lasting protection. We suggest you to keep this case in your collection for being in sync with latest trend in fashion.</str>
    <int name="discount_i">50</int>
    <double name="mrp_d">1200.0</double>
    <str name="store">Flipkart</str>
    <float name="price">599.0</float>
    <str name="categorypath">Mobiles &amp; Tablets|Mobile Accessories|Cases &amp; Covers</str>
    <str name="imageurl">http://img6a.flixcart.com/image/cases-covers/back-cover/p/k/e/mobile-cover-shop-mcs24354-400x400-imae8x3ydhwu6jrd.jpeg</str>
    <str name="name">Mobile Cover Shop Back Cover for Lenovo K920</str>
    <str name="id">ACCE8Y3U5HFZVPKE</str>
    <str name="category">Cases &amp; Covers</str>
    <str name="manu">Mobile Cover Shop</str>
    <str name="producturl">http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/mobile-cover-shop-back-lenovo-k920/p/itme8y3utmh9jzaa?pid=ACCE8Y3U5HFZVPKE</str>
    <date name="last_modified">2016-10-21T07:40:13Z</date>
    <long name="_version_">1548784125873225732</long></doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="description">Mobile Cover Shop having numerous designs of exclusive range for mobile covers, back cover and protective cover and cases. Each cover is made from a special strong and durable plastic material, which provides your gadget with long lasting protection. We suggest you to keep this case in your collection for being in sync with latest trend in fashion.</str>
    <int name="discount_i">50</int>
    <double name="mrp_d">1200.0</double>
    <str name="store">Flipkart</str>
    <float name="price">599.0</float>
    <str name="categorypath">Mobiles &amp; Tablets|Mobile Accessories|Cases &amp; Covers</str>
    <str name="imageurl">http://img6a.flixcart.com/image/cases-covers/back-cover/d/s/u/mobile-cover-shop-mcs23176-400x400-imae8p53hgwggnwb.jpeg</str>
    <str name="name">Mobile Cover Shop Back Cover for Samsung Galaxy S5</str>
    <str name="id">ACCE8Y3TJPXAFDSU</str>
    <str name="category">Cases &amp; Covers</str>
    <str name="manu">Mobile Cover Shop</str>
    <str name="producturl">http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/mobile-cover-shop-back-samsung-galaxy-s5/p/itme8y3tdjn4nqtj?pid=ACCE8Y3TJPXAFDSU</str>
    <date name="last_modified">2016-10-21T07:40:14Z</date>
    <long name="_version_">1548784126891393025</long></doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="description">Mobile Cover Shop having numerous designs of exclusive range for mobile covers, back cover and protective cover and cases. Each cover is made from a special strong and durable plastic material, which provides your gadget with long lasting protection. We suggest you to keep this case in your collection for being in sync with latest trend in fashion.</str>
    <int name="discount_i">50</int>
    <double name="mrp_d">1200.0</double>
    <str name="store">Flipkart</str>
    <float name="price">599.0</float>
    <str name="categorypath">Mobiles &amp; Tablets|Mobile Accessories|Cases &amp; Covers</str>
    <str name="imageurl">http://img5a.flixcart.com/image/cases-covers/back-cover/z/g/e/mobile-cover-shop-mcs23352-400x400-imae8p544uhatwtc.jpeg</str>
    <str name="name">Mobile Cover Shop Back Cover for Samsung Galaxy Note 2 N7100</str>
    <str name="id">ACCE8Y3TGHAK2ZGE</str>
    <str name="category">Cases &amp; Covers</str>
    <str name="manu">Mobile Cover Shop</str>
    <str name="producturl">http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/mobile-cover-shop-back-samsung-galaxy-note-2-n7100/p/itme8y3tcugyxmeb?pid=ACCE8Y3TGHAK2ZGE</str>
    <date name="last_modified">2016-10-21T07:40:15Z</date>
    <long name="_version_">1548784128432799747</long></doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="description">Mobile Cover Shop having numerous designs of exclusive range for mobile covers, back cover and protective cover and cases. Each cover is made from a special strong and durable plastic material, which provides your gadget with long lasting protection. We suggest you to keep this case in your collection for being in sync with latest trend in fashion.</str>
    <int name="discount_i">50</int>
    <double name="mrp_d">1200.0</double>
    <str name="store">Flipkart</str>
    <float name="price">599.0</float>
    <str name="categorypath">Mobiles &amp; Tablets|Mobile Accessories|Cases &amp; Covers</str>
    <str name="imageurl">http://img6a.flixcart.com/image/cases-covers/back-cover/x/3/q/mobile-cover-shop-mcs22843-400x400-imae8p53feah3b2q.jpeg</str>
    <str name="name">Mobile Cover Shop Back Cover for Apple iPhone 6 Plus</str>
    <str name="id">ACCE8Y3TM8YWHX3Q</str>
    <str name="category">Cases &amp; Covers</str>
    <str name="manu">Mobile Cover Shop</str>
    <str name="producturl">http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/mobile-cover-shop-back-apple-iphone-6-plus/p/itme8y3twsyngygp?pid=ACCE8Y3TM8YWHX3Q</str>
    <date name="last_modified">2016-10-21T07:40:15Z</date>
    <long name="_version_">1548784128862715904</long></doc>
</result>
<lst name="debug">
  <str name="rawquerystring">mobile</str>
  <str name="querystring">mobile</str>
  <str name="parsedquery">(+DisjunctionMaxQuery(((manu:mobile)^10.0 | (name:mobile)^0.2 | (category:mobile)^10.0 | (categorypath:mobile)^5.0)))/no_coord</str>
  <str name="parsedquery_toString">+((manu:mobile)^10.0 | (name:mobile)^0.2 | (category:mobile)^10.0 | (categorypath:mobile)^5.0)</str>
  <lst name="explain">
    <str name="ACCE9GQ3BMCHZXYY">
0.9692176 = max of:
  0.9692176 = weight(name:mobile in 311) [], result of:
    0.9692176 = score(doc=311,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0
), product of:
      0.2 = boost
      4.5229306 = idf(docFreq=177649, docCount=16362429)
      1.0714487 = tfNorm, computed from:
        1.0 = termFreq=1.0
        1.2 = parameter k1
        0.75 = parameter b
        8.496009 = avgFieldLength
        7.111111 = fieldLength
</str>
    <str name="ACCE8Y3U5HFZVPKE">
62.168762 = max of:
  62.168762 = weight(manu:mobile in 372) [], result of:
    62.168762 = score(doc=372,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0
), product of:
      10.0 = boost
      6.216876 = idf(docFreq=32829, docCount=16452022)
      1.0 = tfNorm, computed from:
        1.0 = termFreq=1.0
        1.2 = parameter k1
        0.0 = parameter b (norms omitted for field)
  0.8345084 = weight(name:mobile in 372) [], result of:
    0.8345084 = score(doc=372,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0
), product of:
      0.2 = boost
      4.5229306 = idf(docFreq=177649, docCount=16362429)
      0.92253065 = tfNorm, computed from:
        1.0 = termFreq=1.0
        1.2 = parameter k1
        0.75 = parameter b
        8.496009 = avgFieldLength
        10.24 = fieldLength
</str>
    <str name="ACCE8Y3TJPXAFDSU">
62.168762 = max of:
  62.168762 = weight(manu:mobile in 570) [], result of:
    62.168762 = score(doc=570,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0
), product of:
      10.0 = boost
      6.216876 = idf(docFreq=32829, docCount=16452022)
      1.0 = tfNorm, computed from:
        1.0 = termFreq=1.0
        1.2 = parameter k1
        0.0 = parameter b (norms omitted for field)
  0.8345084 = weight(name:mobile in 570) [], result of:
    0.8345084 = score(doc=570,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0
), product of:
      0.2 = boost
      4.5229306 = idf(docFreq=177649, docCount=16362429)
      0.92253065 = tfNorm, computed from:
        1.0 = termFreq=1.0
        1.2 = parameter k1
        0.75 = parameter b
        8.496009 = avgFieldLength
        10.24 = fieldLength
</str>
    <str name="ACCE8Y3TGHAK2ZGE">
62.168762 = max of:
  62.168762 = weight(manu:mobile in 819) [], result of:
    62.168762 = score(doc=819,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0
), product of:
      10.0 = boost
      6.216876 = idf(docFreq=32829, docCount=16452022)
      1.0 = tfNorm, computed from:
        1.0 = termFreq=1.0
        1.2 = parameter k1
        0.0 = parameter b (norms omitted for field)
  0.6644898 = weight(name:mobile in 819) [], result of:
    0.6644898 = score(doc=819,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0
), product of:
      0.2 = boost
      4.5229306 = idf(docFreq=177649, docCount=16362429)
      0.7345788 = tfNorm, computed from:
        1.0 = termFreq=1.0
        1.2 = parameter k1
        0.75 = parameter b
        8.496009 = avgFieldLength
        16.0 = fieldLength
</str>
    <str name="ACCE8Y3TM8YWHX3Q">
62.168762 = max of:
  62.168762 = weight(manu:mobile in 886) [], result of:
    62.168762 = score(doc=886,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0
), product of:
      10.0 = boost
      6.216876 = idf(docFreq=32829, docCount=16452022)
      1.0 = tfNorm, computed from:
        1.0 = termFreq=1.0
        1.2 = parameter k1
        0.0 = parameter b (norms omitted for field)
  0.8345084 = weight(name:mobile in 886) [], result of:
    0.8345084 = score(doc=886,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0
), product of:
      0.2 = boost
      4.5229306 = idf(docFreq=177649, docCount=16362429)
      0.92253065 = tfNorm, computed from:
        1.0 = termFreq=1.0
        1.2 = parameter k1
        0.75 = parameter b
        8.496009 = avgFieldLength
        10.24 = fieldLength
</str>
  </lst>
  <str name="QParser">ExtendedDismaxQParser</str>
  <null name="altquerystring"/>
  <null name="boost_queries"/>
  <arr name="parsed_boost_queries"/>
  <null name="boostfuncs"/>
  <lst name="timing">
    <double name="time">26.0</double>
    <lst name="prepare">
      <double name="time">0.0</double>
      <lst name="query">
        <double name="time">0.0</double>
      </lst>
      <lst name="facet">
        <double name="time">0.0</double>
      </lst>
      <lst name="facet_module">
        <double name="time">0.0</double>
      </lst>
      <lst name="mlt">
        <double name="time">0.0</double>
      </lst>
      <lst name="highlight">
        <double name="time">0.0</double>
      </lst>
      <lst name="stats">
        <double name="time">0.0</double>
      </lst>
      <lst name="expand">
        <double name="time">0.0</double>
      </lst>
      <lst name="debug">
        <double name="time">0.0</double>
      </lst>
    </lst>
    <lst name="process">
      <double name="time">25.0</double>
      <lst name="query">
        <double name="time">0.0</double>
      </lst>
      <lst name="facet">
        <double name="time">0.0</double>
      </lst>
      <lst name="facet_module">
        <double name="time">0.0</double>
      </lst>
      <lst name="mlt">
        <double name="time">0.0</double>
      </lst>
      <lst name="highlight">
        <double name="time">0.0</double>
      </lst>
      <lst name="stats">
        <double name="time">0.0</double>
      </lst>
      <lst name="expand">
        <double name="time">0.0</double>
      </lst>
      <lst name="debug">
        <double name="time">24.0</double>
      </lst>
    </lst>
  </lst>
</lst>
</response>
```

Comment: Can you please post the result set as well for me. I suspect the query is also present in the category that you are boosting tenfold... But I need to see the result to confirm it.

Comment: Thanks Lefty for your comment. I edited the question and added the results.

Comment: Just to make things absolutely clear, could you make two changes please: first, in the search URL, can you please keep the actual keyword so I know what yields the result. Second, can you please post the results in XML as it is easier to read here.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm searching only for single word right now -"mobile". I added the query again with complete response along with debug results in xml. I'm trying to understand how weight is calculated but unable to get it through debug results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As identified, before optimising on the query part of search multiple changes were required in the schema.xml. This link contains detailed information on what I was searching:

http://apprize.info/php/solr_4/6.html

Edit2:
As I was trying to search only mobile whereas category for mobiles was defined as mobilephones in solr data. So, I changed the manufacturer and category fields in schema.xml as follows:

```
  <!--<field name="manu" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="false"/>-->
   <field name="manu" type="text_synonyms_brand" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="false"/>
   <!--<field name="category" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="false"/>-->
   <field name="category" type="text_synonyms_category" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="false"/>
```

and configured respective field-types as follows:

```
<fieldType name="text_synonyms_brand" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<!--<analyzer type="index">
 <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
 <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
</analyzer>-->
<analyzer type="query">
 <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
 <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
 <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" splitOnNumerics="0" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="1" stemEnglishPossessive="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
 <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms_brand.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/> <!-- tokenizerFactory="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/> -->
 <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
</analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType name="text_synonyms_category" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<!--<analyzer type="index">
 <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
 <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
</analyzer>-->
<analyzer type="query">
 <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
 <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
 <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" splitOnNumerics="0" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="1" stemEnglishPossessive="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
 <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms_category.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/> <!-- tokenizerFactory="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>-->
 <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Then in synonyms*.txt I put up few synonyms as follows:

```
# cat synonyms_category.txt
Iphone=>mobilephones
mobile=>mobilephones
phone=>mobilephones
galaxy=>mobilephones

# cat synonyms_brand.txt
Iphone=>apple
galaxy=>samsung
```

After restarting solr (as index time analyzer I commented out), I'm getting the correct results.

Few examples are:

1. for mobile:

Query:

```
http://<solr-url>/solr/<core>/select?debugQuery=on&indent=on&q=(_query_:"{!edismax mm='100%25' qf='manu^2.0' v=$q1}") OR (_query_:"{!edismax mm='100%25' qf='category^2.0' v=$q1}")&q1=mobile&wt=csv
```

Result:

```
mrp_d,manu,description,discount_i,store,_version_,price,categorypath,imageurl,name,id,category,producturl,last_modified
782.0,OEM,,55,Lazada,1549960720168255490,350.0,Mobiles & Tablets|Mobile Phones,http://srv-live.lazada.com.my/p/image-8341802-1-product.jpg,Doogee Voyager2 DG310 5inch Smartphone Android 4.4 Quad Core MT6582 1.3GHZ 3G 1-8GB,LZDOE702ELBSM1QANMY-2279016,Mobile Phones,http://ho.lazada.com.my/SHHSoo?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lazada.com.my%2Fdoogee-voyager2-dg310-5inch-smartphone-android-44-quad-core-mt6582-13ghz-3g-1-8gb-2081438.html%3Foffer_id%3D%7Boffer_id%7D%26affiliate_id%3D%7Baffiliate_id%7D%26offer_name%3D%7Boffer_name%7D_%7Boffer_file_id%7D%26affiliate_name%3D%7Baffiliate_name%7D%26transaction_id%3D%7Btransaction_id%7D&aff_sub=&aff_sub2=&aff_sub3=&aff_sub4=&aff_sub5=,2016-11-03T07:21:57Z
39.0,OEM,,50,Lazada,1549960721000824834,19.4,Mobiles & Tablets|Mobile Phones,http://srv-live.lazada.com.my/p/image-6515112-1-product.jpg,Retro Phone Handset for iPhone 4/4S,LZDOE702ELBTC2CANMY-2320607,Mobile Phones,http://ho.lazada.com.my/SHHSoo?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lazada.com.my%2Fretro-phone-handset-for-iphone-44s-2115156.html%3Foffer_id%3D%7Boffer_id%7D%26affiliate_id%3D%7Baffiliate_id%7D%26offer_name%3D%7Boffer_name%7D_%7Boffer_file_id%7D%26affiliate_name%3D%7Baffiliate_name%7D%26transaction_id%3D%7Btransaction_id%7D&aff_sub=&aff_sub2=&aff_sub3=&aff_sub4=&aff_sub5=,2016-11-03T07:21:58Z
```

2. for iphone:

Query:

```
http://<solr-url>/solr/<core>/select?debugQuery=on&indent=on&q=(_query_:"{!edismax mm='100%25' qf='manu^2.0' v=$q1}") AND (_query_:"{!edismax mm='100%25' qf='category^2.0' v=$q1}")&q1=iphone&wt=csv
```

Result:

```
mrp_d,manu,description,discount_i,store,_version_,price,categorypath,imageurl,name,id,category,producturl,last_modified
3199.0,Apple,,28,Lazada,1549961206837542912,2299.0,Mobiles & Tablets|Mobile Phones,http://srv-live.lazada.com.my/p/image-9072684-1-product.jpg,Apple iPhone 6s 16GB (Gold) Malaysia Set,LZDAP564ELAA2W839ANMY-5749957,Mobile Phones,http://ho.lazada.com.my/SHHSoo?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lazada.com.my%2Fapple-iphone-6s-16gb-gold-malaysia-set-4862709.html%3Foffer_id%3D%7Boffer_id%7D%26affiliate_id%3D%7Baffiliate_id%7D%26offer_name%3D%7Boffer_name%7D_%7Boffer_file_id%7D%26affiliate_name%3D%7Baffiliate_name%7D%26transaction_id%3D%7Btransaction_id%7D&aff_sub=&aff_sub2=&aff_sub3=&aff_sub4=&aff_sub5=,2016-11-03T07:29:42Z
1499.0,Apple,,52,Lazada,1549961206837542915,705.0,Mobiles & Tablets|Mobile Phones,http://srv-live.lazada.com.my/p/image-0684205-490901cdc6628dd90beefa8e05173cdd-product.jpg,100% New Condition (Refurbished) Apple iPhone 5 16GB (White)[Grade A],LZDAP564ELAA2ZP7GANMY-5976742,Mobile Phones,http://ho.lazada.com.my/SHHSoo?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lazada.com.my%2F100-new-condition-refurbished-apple-iphone-5-16gb-whitegrade-a-5024860.html%3Foffer_id%3D%7Boffer_id%7D%26affiliate_id%3D%7Baffiliate_id%7D%26offer_name%3D%7Boffer_name%7D_%7Boffer_file_id%7D%26affiliate_name%3D%7Baffiliate_name%7D%26transaction_id%3D%7Btransaction_id%7D&aff_sub=&aff_sub2=&aff_sub3=&aff_sub4=&aff_sub5=,2016-11-03T07:29:42Z
```